# How to download the flask generated flask html pages?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have created dynamic pages using Flask and I want to download all the pages into a pdf or directory. How can I do that?

http://127.0.0.1:5000/home : This is the main page which has url for other products

1. http://127.0.0.1:5000/product/product0
2. http://127.0.0.1:5000/product/product1
3. http://127.0.0.1:5000/product/product2

Comment: In Flask, the `templates` folder has all the html files for each page. Check if your project structure has this folder because Flask will use this folder to render html pages.

Comment: @amanb page for each product is generated dynamically from product template in templated folder. But that cant be used to convert into pdf directly as the variable spaces are empty

Comment: Dump it to pdf from python after you use `render_template`

Comment: If you want to copy source html to pdf, have a look at Beautifulsoup library